# Cisco RV082 ip conflicts within the router config, I am using a DHCP server configuration

Tags: dhcp

I have an issue with my Cisco RV082 Dual WAN Small Business Router.

Firmware version: v4.0.4.02-tm

I am having ip conflicts within the router config, I am using a DHCP server configuration with the range 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.254

My  Gateway Router Ip is 192.168.1.99

Its asking for a DHCP ip address only in Google chrome and not I.E or Safari

There is also a TAB with RIP options available, when i called cisco they failed to mention anything about RIP when i told them other routers will be joining the network even though i have no physical access to them.

Do I need to allocate static ip's for other routers in the network even though it is a gateway?

Client lease times are also different for routers and computers. there is no option available in my firmware to change this.

Comment: My Router Ip is 192.168.1.99 and the internet runs fine but people complain about personal wireless routers, my best guess is by looking @ the local mac addresses they seem to have a lease time of only 60 sec where the default lease of ip's given by the dhcp are 1 day long.

Do i need to adjust any rip settings?

Do i need to Set SNMP protocols?

The subnet of the LAN is 255.255.255.0 and the subnet of both WAN modems are 255.255.255.252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said people are complaining about personal wireless routers. If they are trying to connect personal wireless routers to this network, most likely the problem is that you are using 192.168.1.0 for your network and the personal wireless router is doing the same. You should change your network to 192.168.200.0 or something other than 192.168.1.0. Then, you won't be conflicting with the personal wireless routers out there.

Comment: omg your a genius :)